# How to fix "property destructuring pattern expected" error?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting this error:

[image: vscode screenshot]

Same error when I try to compile:

```
c:\...\tsx-test>ntsc app/main.tsx
app/components/Note.tsx(13,31): error TS1180: Property destructuring pattern expected.
```

But I don't know what it's expecting. What's the property syntax?

I'm pretty sure this works as-is in ES6. Is the syntax different in TypeScript?

Note that I'm using TypeScript 1.5.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure this works as-is in ES6.

the `{a, b, ...rest} = props` pattern is supported by TypeScript now. Just update to the latest compiler and it will work without error.

## More

Some docs on the TypeScript destructuring:

http://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html

Comment: Ah. Worked with Babel; didn't realize it was ES7. Ticket is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103) for anyone interested.

Comment: Is this still the case? 08-29-2016 ? Because I have this same issue today...

Comment: @Simon, unfortunately it's still not implemented. You may follow [#2103](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103) and #[10727](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727)

Comment: What about now in 2020?

Comment: @Waltari supported now 